# If the normal reaction force is due to electrostatic repulsion, then why do only solids exert it and not fluids?

Tags: forces, electrons

I have read that the normal force is due to the electrons on the surface of two materials in contact repelling each other. However, liquids obviously also have electrons that would repel the electrons on the surface of a solid object, if that object was placed in the liquid, but no-one ever talks about the normal force with fluids, only about upthrust, which is due to gravity and not to electrostatic repulsion. Is it perhaps that fluids do repel solids to some extent, but that the solids can still move through the fluids in spite of this because the fluids are more spaced out and less strongly held together? But if so, then why does no one ever seem to factor in the normal force when considering why objects float etc.?

Answer (score 6):

The crucial difference here between solids and liquids is that the former are bonded well enough to sustain a [shear stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_stress). The idealized liquid has no such shear strength; its [shear modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus) is zero. This is a defining characteristic of liquids: they rearrange easily, deforming to match the shape of their containers.

(As you note, both solids and liquids are made of atoms that repel similarly, but the precise thing they resist similarly is uniform compression or pressure. This is quantified by the [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus). You can compare various moduli conceptually and numerically [here](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/overrating_youngs_modulus.htm).)

When you set a solid object on the ground, shear stresses arise within the materials (ultimately arising from the compressive stress caused by the force balance between the weight and the normal force; [Mohr's circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%27s_circle) is a handy geometrical way of envisioning how normal stresses lead to shear stresses).

If you place a solid object on a pool of liquid, no normal force can be sustained, because the consequent shear stresses cannot be sustained. Instead, the object sinks according to [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) until the weight of the liquid it displaces equals its own weight.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer; I have upvoted it. If I have correctly understood, then you seem to be saying that the normal force is actually just due to how much a substance resists being compressed, so how does this link with what I read about the normal force being due to electrons repelling each other? Is it that things partly resist compression precisely because the electrons around the atoms resist being squashed into each other?

Comment: I am not saying the normal force depends on the stiffness; the normal force for a 1 N weight of steel or rubber is 1 N in both cases. I'm saying that since a normal force induces shear stresses, you won't see a free liquid support a normal force in the context described here. However, liquids do resist hydrostatic pressure, which doesn't induce shear. The resistance comes from electron repulsion, nucleus repulsion, and the Pauli exclusion principle.

Answer (score 2):

To a certain extent, this is a matter of nomenclature and definition.  A normal force is a resistance that a solid surface exerts on something that is pushing on it, and that normal force is always perpendicular to the solid surface.  Since "normal" means "perpendicular" to a mathematician, such forces are called normal forces.

When an object is immersed in a liquid, that object pushes on the liquid, the liquid redistributes itself around the object, and that liquid puts pressure on the object.  The force that the liquid puts on the object that is immersed in it, is equal to pressure multiplied by area.  For various differential areas on any given regularly or irregularly shaped immersed object, the differential forces exerted are always perpendicular to each differential area, and are equal to the local pressure multiplied by the magnitude of that differential area.  The integral of those forces over all differential areas of that object results in the buoyant force on that object, which is counted as a single force, but that resultant force still comes from the summation of all the differential "normal" forces that the liquid puts on the immersed object.

Answer (score 1):

In a solid, atoms hold their neighbors rigidly in place. This makes the whole solid rigid. In a liquid, atoms attract each other and stick to each other, but do not have specific positions where the neighbors must be.

In both the bonds are caused by electromagnetic forces as described by quantum mechanics.